# ¿ Cómo convertir un objeto completo, con propiedades y métodos, para su serialización?

Tags: javascript

Teniendo en cuenta que provengo del C#, me ha encantado la nueva forma en javascript de crear clases y objetos, con ECMA 6, casi idéntica. El problema viene con la conversión, que no es un objeto "completo" convertido, ya que usando los métodos JSON solo se consiguen convertir las propiedades y sus valores, pero no sus métodos. Aquí pongo un ejemplo de lo que quiero decir:

```
"esversion: 6";
"use strict";

    class Coche{
        constructor(marca){
            this.marca = marca;
            this.velocidad = 0;
        }

        acelera(){
            if(this.velocidad < 341){
                this.velocidad = this.velocidad + 10;
            }

            return this.velocidad;
        }

        reduce(){
            if(this.velocidad > 10){
                this.velocidad = this.velocidad - 10;
            }

            return this.velocidad;
        }
    }

    var miFerrari = new Coche("Ferrari");
    var miFerrariJSON = JSON.stringify(miFerrari);

    console.log("miFerrari: " + miFerrariJSON); 
    // miFerrari: {"marca":"Ferrari","velocidad":0}

    // En este momento se serializaría el objeto, 
    // para usarlo en otra sesión de la aplicación.
    // Posteriormente, se recuperaría desde el almacenamiento local,
    // y se cargaría en una variable para poder usarlo en la aplicación.

    var miFerrariObj = JSON.parse(miFerrariJSON);
    console.log("miFerrariObj: " + miFerrariObj); // miFerrariObj: [object Object]
    console.log("miFerrariObj.marca: " + miFerrariObj.marca); // miFerrariObj.marca: Ferrari
    console.log("miFerrariObj.acelera(): " + miFerrariObj.acelera()); // Uncaught TypeError: miFerrariObj.acelera is not a function
```

Comment: No es posible parsear a JSON las funciones en Javascript , en la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/stringify) está muy claro **Las funciones no son un tipo de dato valido por lo cual estas no funcionaran.**

Comment: Bueno eso es algo que ya sabía, como he demostrado anteriormente. Se trata de encontrar otra solución, por eso planteo el problema. Saludos.

Comment: ¿Para qué utilizarías concretamente la serialización de tu objeto?

Comment: La serialización la usaría para guardar objetos de la aplicación, que posteriormente cargaría en una nueva sesión de aplicación.

Answer (score 0):

Puede intentar lo siguiente:

```js
var Coche = {
  constructor: function(marca) {
    this.marca = marca;
    this.velocidad = 0;
  },

  acelera: function() {
    //menor o igual
    if (this.velocidad <= 341) {
      this.velocidad = this.velocidad + 10;
    }

    return this.velocidad;
  },

  reduce: function() {
    //mayor o igual
    if (this.velocidad >= 10) {
      this.velocidad = this.velocidad - 10;
    }
    return this.velocidad;
  }
}

//lo declara así
var miFerrari = Coche;
//así agrega marca y velocidad;
miFerrari.constructor('ferrari');

console.log(miFerrari);

//no lo pase a cadena/string solo envia la variable 
//"miFerrari"

//aquí debe de ir solo la variable debido a que es un objeto
console.log(miFerrari); // miFerrariObj: [object Object]
console.log("miFerrariObj.marca: " + miFerrari.marca);
console.log("miFerrariObj.acelera(): " + miFerrari.acelera());
console.log("miFerrariObj.reduce(): " + miFerrari.reduce());
```

los 'IF' con el operador '>=' o '<=' y no convertir a 'string', solo pasa la variable.

Comment: Maikol, gracias por esta buena solución, la verdad yo también había pensado en algo similar, sin embargo esto me sigue planteando dos problemas: el primero, no quiero romper mi esquema mental sobre la POO basada en C# y que ahora tan bien implementó ECMA6, y que me ha costado muy poco adaptarme. Esta resolución "recarga" de sintaxis innecesaria, como la definición de los métodos, o la construcción de la instancia miFerrari. El otro problema es que ya tengo la aplicación casi terminada con más de dos mil líneas de código, con 10 clases definidas y anidadas entre sí, (sigue-->)

Comment: que construyen un único objeto, este objeto es appFull que contiene todos los demás objetos, propiedades y métodos. La solución ideal para mí, sería coger el objeto appFull y convertirlo para serializarlo.

Comment: @FrankMascarell, la verdad aun no estoy 100% familiarizado con POO, actualmente esa es la estructura que uso para 'simular' los OBJETOS en JavaScript y me siento muy cómodo con ella. Respecto a lo de la sintaxis innecesaria,  es cuestión de acostumbrarse, no es tanta tampoco. Y a lo de convertir todo su código, primero piense en los pro y contras.  suerte!

Comment: Creo que lo mejor será construir mi propia función, que convierta el objeto en un string a mi gusto, así que manos a la obra. :)